# FFMPeg generated video: Audio has 'glitches' when uploaded to YouTube

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, codec

I've generated a voice from Azure AI Speech at 48KHz and 96K Bit Rate, generated a video of some stock footages and I'm trying to combine all of that with a background music.
The voice-over is generated per setence, so that I know how long each setence is and to include relevant video footage.

I'm using FFMpeg through the [FFMpegCore](https://github.com/rosenbjerg/FFMpegCore) nuget package.

**The problem**

After the video is complete with background music, I play it on my computer and it's perfect (no audio glitches, music keeps playing). But when uploaded to youtube it has 'breaks' in the music inbetween sentences (basically everytime a new voice-fragment is starting).

**Example:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieNvQ2TNq44

**The code**

All of the footage is combined with mostly `FFMpeg.Join(string output, string[] videos)`. These video files also contain the voice-overs (per sentance).

After that I try to add the music like this:

```cs
   string outputTimelineWithMusicPath = _workingDir + $@"\{videoTitle}_withmusic.mp4";
    FFMpegArguments
        .FromFileInput(inputVideoPath)
        .AddFileInput(musicPath)
        .OutputToFile(outputPath, true, options => options
            .CopyChannel()
            .WithAudioCodec(AudioCodec.Aac)
            .WithAudioBitrate(AudioQuality.Good)
            .UsingShortest(true)
            .WithCustomArgument("-filter_complex \"[0:a]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,apad[0a];[1]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,volume=0.05[1a];[0a][1a]amerge[a]\" -map 0:v -map \"[a]\" -ac 2"))
        .ProcessSynchronously();
```

I've tried to mess around with the CustomArgument, but so far no success.

For example, I thought removing `apad` from the argument so no 'blank spots' are added, should perhaps fix the issue. Also tried to use `amix` instead of `amerge`.

**Last try**

I've tried to first make sure both files had the same sample rate, in the hope to fix the issue. So far, no success

```cs
    string outputVideoVoicePath = _workingDir + $@"\{title}_voiceonly_formatting.mp4";
    string musicReplacePath = _workingDir + $@"\{title}_music_formatted.aac";
    FFMpegArguments
    .FromFileInput(inputVideoPath)
    .OutputToFile(outputVideoVoicePath, true, options => options
        .WithAudioCodec(AudioCodec.Aac)
        .WithAudioBitrate(128)
        .WithAudioSamplingRate(44100)
    )
    .ProcessSynchronously();
    
    FFMpegArguments
        .FromFileInput(music.FilePath)
        .OutputToFile(musicReplacePath, true, options => options
            .WithAudioCodec(AudioCodec.Aac)
            .WithAudioBitrate(256) //also tried 96 (which is original format)
            .WithAudioSamplingRate(44100)
        )
        .ProcessSynchronously();
    
    
    Console.WriteLine("Add music...");
    var videoTitle = Regex.Replace(title, "[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
    string outputTimelineWithMusicPath = _workingDir + $@"\{videoTitle}_withmusic.mp4";
    FFMpegArguments
        .FromFileInput(outputVideoVoicePath)
        .AddFileInput(musicReplacePath)
        .OutputToFile(outputTimelineWithMusicPath, true, options => options
            .CopyChannel()
            .WithAudioCodec(AudioCodec.Aac)
            .WithAudioBitrate(AudioQuality.Good)
            .UsingShortest(true)
            .WithCustomArgument("-filter_complex \"[0:a]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo[0a];[1]aformat=fltp:44100:stereo,volume=0.05[1a];[0a][1a]amix=inputs=2[a]\" -map 0:v -map \"[a]\" -ac 2"))
        .ProcessSynchronously();
    return outputTimelineWithMusicPath;
```

I'm not much of an expert when it comes to audio/video codecs. I do scale each stock video to 24fps, 1920x1080 and the music has a original bitrate of 256Kbps / 44100 sample rate (so I probably don't even have to convert the audio file).